# Change primary language in the new iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Apple recently released a new version of iTunes Connect.
I just want to change the primary language of my app, but the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html at the bottom) is now deprecated.

Anyone solved this problem?

[image]

Comment: same thing with my app... its stuck with danish and i need english.

Comment: I answered my question

Comment: I am not able to change primary language of the app in new version. Primary Language Option under App Information on iTunes is not actionable there. Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: @JérômeBoé how were you able to solve this issue? I have the problem as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to change the primary language after being accepted by the appstore.

Despite what the documentation says, it seems that changing the primary language is impossible in "Prepare for submission" state.

Comment: Can you explain what you did to make this work?
I'm in "Prepare for submission" i added a language and i want to make it primary and remove the old language.

Comment: So when it become possible? In Review or on sale state?

Comment: @TomSawyer according to Philipp here below it looks like the app has to be in "ready for sale" state (Philipp said: "[...] As soon as the version is approved + ready for sale [...]".

Answer (score 6):

My Apps > App Store > App Information > Primary Language

[image]

UPDATE:

Please check Localization in your project. Maybe only "French" is showing?

[image]

Comment: I can't edit the primary language (I edited my post and attached a screenshot)

Comment: I am not able to change primary language of the app in new version. Primary Language Option under App Information on iTunes is not actionable there. Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: same problem , please help

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to make it work without having to get accepted by the App Store.

1. In Localizable Information, click on the language and choose a new language you want to add as primary language.
2. Very important. **Hit Save** at top right corner.
3. Go down to General Information. You will find now that Primary Language becomes a drop-down menu with new language that you just added. You can proceed to change your primary language and then Save.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm, many thanks!. After this, I was able to delete the initial primary language as well. This should be the accepted answer. A neat work around without the need to get the app approved.

Answer (score 1):

For those still having problems changing your primary language, you first need to submit a new version of your app which has at least 2 localizations (for me e.g. i started only with german and then german and english). German was my initial primary language.
As soon as the version is approved + ready for sale(dont forget to add the localization in your App-Information as well (add new language)) THEN you can change the primary language in the App information.

Sorry for my english, new here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to untick 'Use XXXCOUNTRYXXX Apple Watch' under 'Apple Watch' in Media Manager (and any others that may be ticked by default). I was then able to change the primary language.

[image: Screenshot of tickbox]