# Unspecific iTunesConnect Localization Error

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios11

iTunes Connect won't let me submit my app for review; it says "this site contains at least one error." Nothing is highlighted except for a tiny red exclamation mark next to the primary (and only) localization, English (US). *No explanation*.

[image: iTunesConnect Localization Drop-Down]

I'm using xCode 9; app localization is en-US, as is the primary language. The app itself is a legacy app jerry-rigged to run with iOS 11.

Any ideas are highly appreciated, as this issue keeps me from releasing the app!

Comment: The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929345/ios-app-submission-error-localization-related-issue) doesn't work anymore; I uploaded a 5.5" screenshot alright, nothing else being possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, iTunes Connect has a horrible user experience. Here are a couple of things to check for if you are updating an old app:

- **Screenshots**: Go into the Media Manager and check if you have some kind of "old" screenshots lingering around. Try to delete them manually and only upload iPhone 5.5-inch and iPad 12.9-inch screenshots and check the "use X.X inch screenshots" checkbox
- **App Name**: Check if the app name is below 30 characters
- **Categories**: Apple recently trashed a couple of categories, just make sure everything is alright here
- **Review Contact Info**: Not sure when they added it, but you need to provide the phone number in the following format: +12 345 678 90 (without the spaces)

Sometimes the following can help as well: 
Create new language > Make it Primary Language > Delete English > Add English > Make it Primary language > Delete "helper" language

Comment: Thanks Max, but that wasn't it. I've got exactly one 5.5" screenshot, meticulously pruned names and categories, and well-formatted phone numbers... Anyway, I haven't been able to change the primary language.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844091/change-primary-language-in-the-new-itunes-connect) indicates that the primary language can be changed **after** the app's accepted...

Comment: It's not possible. That change will only get reflected with a new version